# Does System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient support CRAM-MD5 authentication?

Tags: .net, smtpclient, system.net.mail

Does System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient support CRAM-MD5 authentication, and if so, do I need to do anything to enable it?

MSDN appears to be silent on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not supported (in .NET Framework 4.5.2).

Digging through the [reference source of SmtpClient](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System/a.html#ebaa2d61cfed8051) reveals that `System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection` is used to create the SMTP connection. [Its source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/mail/smtpconnection.cs) shows that (only) the following authentication modes are supported:

- LOGIN
- NTLM
- GSSAPI
- WDIGEST